# Inserting one table primary key into other using JDBC in SQL Developer

Tags: java, jdbc, foreign-keys, oracle-sqldeveloper, primary-key

I had 2 tables , and I want to insert one table primary key into other which is referencing the first table.
Table1 has EMP_ID (primary key) , EMP_CODE
Table2 has EMP_ID(Foreign key referencing table1) , EMP_DET, EMP_SAL

See the code below in which I'm getting error

```
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class merge {
public static void main(String[] args ) {
     String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:d12fr13"; 
     String user = "username"; 
     String pass = "username"; 
     Connection con =null;
     int EMP_ID =0;
     PreparedStatement ps = null;
     String inserttable1 = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (EMP_CODE) VALUES (?)";
     String  inserttable2  ="INSERT INTO TABLE2 (EMP_ID ,EMP_DET,EMP_SAL) VALUES (?,?,?)";
     
     ResultSet generatedKeys = null;
     try (Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);)//Connection
     {
             myConn.setAutoCommit(false);//Turn off auto commit
             try (PreparedStatement myPs = myConn.prepareStatement(inserttable1,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS))//Prepared Statement
             {
                 myPs.setInt(1,100);

                 myPs.executeUpdate();

                 myConn.commit();

                 generatedKeys = myPs.getGeneratedKeys();
                 if (generatedKeys.next())//Return ID
                 {
                     EMP_ID= generatedKeys.getInt(1);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     throw new SQLException("No generated EMP_ID returned");
                 }

             }//end of try
             finally 
             {
                 if (generatedKeys != null) generatedKeys.close();
             }//end of finally
             try (PreparedStatement myPs = myConn.prepareStatement(inserttable2))//Prepared Statement
             {
                 myPs.setInt(1,EMP_ID);
                 myPs.setInt(2, 101);
                 myPs.setInt(3, 102);

                 myPs.executeUpdate();

                 myConn.commit();

                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insert Successful");
             }//end of try
     }
}
```

Error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at oracle.jdbc.driver.JavaToJavaConverter.main(JavaToJavaConverter.java:2552)

Comment: You forgot to include the error text in your question. Also, while you are editing it, please format the code properly, from the start.

Comment: Kindly see now , Edited the code and also  attached the error

Comment: Given the `oracle.jdbc.driver.JavaToJavaConverter.main` in the stacktrace, it looks like you are trying to run an application inside the Oracle JDBC driver jar instead of your own application.

Comment: Didn't get it , Can you elaborate?

Comment: Can you put the *whole* stack trace, please? Format it as code for it to align properly. We need to see the part where your actual code connects to all this.

Comment: Also, please format the code properly. It's best if you put it in an IDE and use its format function. But if you don't, please make sure indentation is accurate. It looks like you are using `myConn` outside of the scope where it was initialized. That's bad practice, and could lead to chains of exceptions. And continuing after an exception has occurred is also bad practice.

Comment: Edited the code , Kindly check